# How do i call methods from JRuby into my Java code?

Tags: java, ruby, variables, methods, jruby

Now i have a method in my Ruby script code and basicaly its returning a variable and this variable is pretty important to my code in java, So what i whant in my java code is to call this method that is in the Ruby script and the script returns a value and this value shall be assigned to my variable that i have..

Here is the code i have in ruby.. And i whant to call it in java and use what it returns and put it in a variable ..

```
def numberMethod
  number = 3
return number
end
```

If you know where i can read about it or if you know how to solve it please give me a comment or answear!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reading [RedBridge](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/RedBridge)

Comment: Which part in there explains about calling methods when i look through it i don't find anything..